# Does Monaco have the ability to display only some lines

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there any function in Monaco that only displays part of the lines while other lines are hidden by default but can be displayed by clicking the button?

[click before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN4ZX.png)

[click after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfv4b.png)

URL: https://github.com/vuejs/docs-next/commit/240097350da0422a2fc2ee340ae410f8266255e9

Comment: Can you tell me why you reverted my edit to make your questions better readable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a functionality and it's called "code folding" (or just "folding").

Expanded:

[image]

Collapsed:

[image]

Note: monaco-editor also supports a diff mode: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-diffeditor-inline-diff-example

Comment: Hey brother, this is not the function I want. I want to display a piece of code by default like github. Click the plus button to expand the code downwards or upwards